# Visual Studio 2022 Address Sanitizer fails to compile C++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Trying to use Address Sanitizer on C++ Win64 project in Debug with Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.6) and getting the following error message:

*1...\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\modules\std.ixx : fatal  error C1358: module (key=0xbfda) information unavailable*

Followed the [AddressSanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170) manual and turned off all incompatible options. Nothing helps.

Has anybody experienced this? Any advice to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue(both Version 17.7.0 and 17.8.0 Preview 1.0 in C++latest) and reported to the Developer Community.
(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/import-std;-with-address-sanitizer-optio/10439535)

If you use only headers and not `import std;`, etc., then address sanitizer option works but you need to turn off `Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules` in Project Property(`Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `All Options`).

[image]